# How can I prevent a device from being installed

Tags: windows, windows-8, drivers, windows-8.1, wireless-adapter

I have a wireless card that is causing me some serious trouble.

I need the device to stop installing the driver it is currently using. I went into the hardware settings and set it to ask me what to do, and not use windows update.

I uninstalled the device, then I unplugged and replugged. Despite this, windows still selects the driver that is already present and re-installs the device. On other devices, I usually see an advanced option under uninstall that allows me to permanently remove the drivers, but I did not see that option for this one. I had to go nuclear and wipe out the specific driver (from all backups in the system) for the device to prevent it from being automatically installed. Is there an easier way to do this in the future?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent the system to install the device? Just let it and then in the device manager set it as "Don't use this device" so it cannot create any trouble whatsoever.

Comment: Because this disables the device at the system level. I'm using VirtualBox to pass this device through to a virtual machine. This requires the device to be present on the machine, but without it being installed with drivers and taken over by Windows.